# Assigning probabilities to an Autocomplete function

Tags: text, natural-language

I have created an autocomplete function based on WordList.

```
auto = Autocomplete[WordList["KnownWords"]]
```

And if I use this on the letters "ga", it will provide me with a long list of possible words. Is it possible to create a probability list from these to choose the most commonly used one?

I am aware this is more of a theoretical question and am happy with any answers that point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### QUICK TAKE

You can make use of `WordFrequencyData` and define

```
auto=Autocomplete[WordList["KnownWords"]];
hint[word_]:=First[Keys[ReverseSort[DeleteMissing[WordFrequencyData[auto[word],IgnoreCase->True]]]]]
```

It will give you most popular hint, for examplle:

```
hint["gath"]
```

> "gathered"

#### DETAILS

So starting from hints for say "gath"

```
auto = Autocomplete[WordList["KnownWords"]];
hints = auto["gath"]
```

> {"gather", "gatherer", "gathered", "gathering"}

you can find and sort reversely their frequencies in typical English:

```
freq=ReverseSort[DeleteMissing[WordFrequencyData[auto["gath"],IgnoreCase->True]]]
```

> <|gathered->0.000013772,gathering->8.98098*10^-6,gather->7.46439*10^-6,gatherer->3.42559*10^-7|>

Then get already order hints as

```
Keys[freq]
```

> {gathered,gathering,gather,gatherer}

or just the most frequent one

```
First[Keys[freq]]
```

> "gathered"

#### NOTE

`WordFrequencyData` can slow down for too many words as it accesses Wolfram servers to download data and needs internet. One trick to speed this up - is to pre-download and save `WordFrequencyData` for your set of words. It might take a long time for many 1000s of words, but is doable if you split it in cycles by, say, 100 words.

Comment: Just to follow-up on how to speed it up, how can I pre-download certain words?

Comment: @TimB `prefetch = WordFrequencyData[{"cat", "dog"}]` etc. then use `prefetch` variable to work with or save with `Put` `Get` etc. Read some docs on `WordFrequencyData`.