# Removing banal words from a list

Tags: string-manipulation, data, parsing, natural-language

NB: I am aware of the `DeleteStopwords` symbol.

I want to remove from a list of words the ones that are likely to be more banal. So for instance if we have

```
{"exegesis", "mystification", "bread", "synthesis", "dog", "autonomy", "develop", "enthusiastic", "house"}
```

then I would like a function that is likely to remove `"bread"`, `"dog"`, and `"house"` while leaving the other words in the list.

Any ideas for implementing such a thing? It doesn't have to be incredibly robust; I'm generating lists of words for games where the object is to guess the word.

Please add any useful tags; I couldn't think of any that applied very well.

Comment: Why not create a list of words that you consider banal, then remove them with `DeleteCases[]` or something similar. Also, maybe define what is "banal" in this context? If the game was about dogs or food, surely 'house' and 'dog' would not be banal.

Comment: Might WordFrequencyData[] be a starting point for a simple commonality "score"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please also see a related problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/213531/13), it might give you more ideas. Words can be banal wrt all words in the dictionary or wrt some particular list of words. Let's consider the later case. `WordFrequencyData` gives the frequency of word in typical published English text. Within a given list of words you can find the max-frequency word and rescale the rest of the words according to it. Then a threshold to cut off more popular words will be always between 0 and 1.

```
banal[w_,t_]:=With[{freq=WordFrequencyData[w]},
Keys[Select[freq/Max[freq],#<=t&]]]
```

For your set of words:

```
words={"exegesis", "mystification", "bread", "synthesis", 
"dog", "autonomy", "develop", "enthusiastic", "house"};
```

and threshold $0.1$ we get

```
In[]:= banal[words,.1]
Out[]= {exegesis,mystification,synthesis,autonomy,enthusiastic}
```

with the dropped words being:

```
In[]:= Complement[words,%]
Out[]= {bread,develop,dog,house}
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! I was unable to discover `WordFrequencyData` on my own and it is precisely the sort of symbol I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a word is "banal" is a subjective judgment.  If you want to approach it in a statistical way, I'd try a TF/IDF approach.  You'll find no shortage of references about it on the web.

Here's the basic idea.  Suppose you're building a search index over a bunch of documents.

TF = term frequency: How many times a word appears in one particular document

IDF = inverse document frequency: 1 over the number of documents where the word appears.  So, the more documents the word appears in, the smaller this factor becomes. 1 over 10 documents is a bigger number than 1 over 100,000 documents.

You can think of this roughly as a generalization of the stopword concept.  Rather than manually list out your stopwords, you use automated means to count words over a set of documents and come up with what you might think of as a distinctiveness score.  The word "the" might appear many times within one document, but it also appears across many documents, so it's not a very distinctive word.

So suppose you're building a system like Google, and the user searches for "the green xylophone".  You probably don't want to rank documents very high just because they contain "the".  However, "xylophone" is a more distinctive word in the sense that it appear in far fewer documents, so you might consider a match on that word to be more important in ranking a document up.  "green" would be somewhere in the middle, probably.

Comment: I see you're a new contributor, welcome! Do you have some Wolfram Language code for this idea? It sounds very neat & well thought out. It would be great if you could show us how to do what you're suggesting here :D